# Install macports port on brew

Tags: macos, homebrew, macports

Can I install macports port like this https://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=name&substr=ftpsync on brew ?

Does brew have mechanism for that?

Comment: Not a programming question - try https://apple.stackexchange.com ?

Answer (score 0):

No, Homebrew has its own way of defining packages. It uses Ruby files called "formulæ" (or "formulas") to describe how to install a piece of software. It doesn’t support any other way.

You need to translate the port into [Homebrew’s format](https://docs.brew.sh/Formula-Cookbook) in order to make it work.